# CX_Freeze issue after build in use tl.testing?

Tags: python

I am doing a small game in which I use "from tl.testing.thread import ThreadJoiner" to execute threads when executing from console the program as such works but when creating the executable with the help of cx_freeze I have the problem that when executing the program I get an error respect tl tells me that the module tl is not found and the program is not executed.

the error is this:

```
C:\Users\The.hacker\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packgages\cx_freeze\initscripts\_startup_.py",line 14,in run
 module.run()
file:
C:\Users\The.hacker\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packgages\cx_freeze\initscripts\Console.py",line 26,in run
 exec(code,m._dict_))
 file "the_last_warrior",line 11,in <module>
Modulenotfounderror:no module named tl
```

on line 11 is the `from tl.testing.thread import ThreadJoiner`
now the image:
my file main is "the_last_warrior.py"

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter
from tl.testing.thread import ThreadJoiner
import threading
import datetime
from threading import Thread
```

has more than 1600 lines,In itself, how would the correct import of this module be? (from tl.testing.thread import ThreadJoiner)
picture of error:
[console_vs_exe.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VsaaQ.jpg)

Comment: Try adding entire `tl.testing.thread` in the packages. I had a similar problem and it worked for me.

Comment: hello, also probe but I get an error before doing the build of the setup.py "ImportError: No module named 'tl.testing.thread'".

Comment: I solved the problem by copying the package manually, as I do with the question? Or does a moderator deactivate it?

Comment: You can post what you did as an answer and mark it as solved? It might be able to help others too

Comment: Thank you, I will approve the answer within 9 hours as it allows me to approve it after that time passes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying many things, I solved by copying the package directly from the folder "Lib \ site-packages" my package "tl" and paste it into the Lib folder of my program already ready after using the setup.py the program executes runs as I expected.
[image: my_game_run.jpg]